# How to Select Choices input field having same class, type, Xpath everything is same

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I have two input fields to enter choices which have same class, type. Id is different by it is dynamic and create on run time so i can't use id.I used indexing ,it's not working properly.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text'][@placeholder='Provide a response entry that customers can select'][1]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text'][@placeholder='Provide a response entry that customers can select'][1]")).sendKeys("Iphone 6");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text'][@placeholder='Provide a response entry that customers can select'][2]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text'][@placeholder='Provide a response entry that customers can select'][2]")).sendKeys("Iphone 7");
```

I used indexing in given image link.

[click link to view code in organized way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzejT.png)

Index 1 works in this case but unable to find index 2.

Given inspected html code is below of input field 1 and field 2

Field 1
[Input field 1 image Xpath  link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4sBm.png)

field 2
[Input field 2 image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhKC2.png)

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: try with it's id. It's different. One is "input_168" and the other is "input_170".

Comment: Yeah i know but id is dynamic and change on run time for example i run the test first time may be id value can "input_168" and "input_170". And when i will run test second time it could be "input_262" and "input_264"

Comment: @DebanjanB okay i mentioned the code. First i thought it's not looking properly readable.

Comment: @MuneebAkhtar I have indented your _code trials_ but for an effective answer you still need to provide text formatted relevant HTML

Comment: @Hiten Yeah i know but id is dynamic and change on run time for example i run the test first time may be id value can "input_168" and "input_170". And when i will run test second time it could be "input_262" and "input_264".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these two `input`s are always in this sequence (so the first `input` is always first and second always second)

You can use:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='text'][@placeholder='Provide a response entry that customers can select'])[1]")).click();


driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='text'][@placeholder='Provide a response entry that customers can select'])[2]")).click();
```

At the same time I have corrected the syntax in indexing

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Anand 's answer, you can simplify a little:

```
WebElement button1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='text' and @placeholder='Provide a response entry that customers can select'])[1]"));
WebElement button2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='text' and @placeholder='Provide a response entry that customers can select'])[2]"));
```

I think it's a little easier to read using `and` instead of stacking brackets.

I use it similarly for widgets:

```
WebElement header = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'panel')]/div[contains(@class,'panel-heading') and text()[contains(.,'News Feed')]]"));
```